# getMeasuredHeight vs getMeasuredHeightAndState

Tags: android, android-layout, view, android-view

I have already looked at the source code. I have read the docs. But I still don't understand how these two values compare and contrast. Also I was surprised to see

```
public final int getMeasuredHeight() {
    return mMeasuredHeight & MEASURED_SIZE_MASK;
}
```

Why the bitwise AND?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mMeasuredHeight is one integer value that contains two distinct pieces of information about the view.

Obviously, the first piece is the size. There is a reasonable maximum height that a view can have, and it is far smaller than the maximum integer. So, you can use the highest bits in the integer value to set flags.

In this case, the flag being set is MEASURED_STATE_TOO_SMALL, which is the second piece. By setting this bit to a 1, the view is declaring that the "measured size is smaller that the space the view would like to have."

getMeasuredHeight does a bitwise AND to eliminate that bit by any function using the raw pixel value.